The "Unsave this question" feature returns "An error occurred" message
When you use the Save this question > Manage > Save To feature, and then navigate back to the question in the saved list, the "Unsave this question" feature returns an "An error occurred" message. Now my list is growing bigger and I can't unsave the questions.

This issue occurs exclusively with older lists created before the Stack Exchange developers implemented a database change that was not fully adapted to accommodate pre-existing lists.


I can reproduce it too, here on Meta even. Sounds like a bug, maybe one the developers should take a look. It is already tagged as [bug], so I think they are aware of it, though it may take some time for them to get here.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos The workaround I found was to delete the list and then create a new one. This new list is now properly registered in their database and now functions properly. So they probably made some database change that did not appropriately adjust to the already-existing old lists. The new lists you create will work.

Nice find, thanks for sharing. That will do until we get a proper fix
